# Django Form Init Check Field for errors to apply CSS class to field

Tags: django, forms

I am currently running into a problem I cannot solve.

I have written myself a simple Form to update a user's password. Within the constructor I would like to add a specific class onto the input field, if there is an error. Basically this happens after a POST request and once I have validated the form.

The class:

```
class UpdatePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    """
    This form is used at two places:
        - A user has been logged out and needs to reset the password
        - A user is in the control panel and wants to update the password
    """

    user = None
    def_error_messages = {
        'current_password_not_correct': _("Derzeitiges Passwort nicht ok."),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
        'password_tooshort': _("The password is too short."),
        'password_tooeasy': _("The password is too easy or based on dictionary word."),
    }

    PASS_MIN_LENGTH = 8

    current_password = forms.CharField(label=_("Derzeitiges Passwort"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdatePasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for f in self.fields:
            if self.fields[f].error_messages is not None:
                logger.debug(self.fields[f].error_messages)
                self.fields[f].widget.attrs['class'] = 'invalid'

    def clean_current_password(self):
        current_password = self.cleaned_data.get('current_password')
        if current_password and self.user:
            if check_password(current_password, self.user.password):
                return True

            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.def_error_messages['current_password_not_correct'],
                code='current_password_not_correct',
            )
        return False

    def has_digits(self, val):
        digits = False
        if any(c.isdigit() for c in val):
            digits = True
        return digits

    def has_alpha(self, val):
        ascii = False
        if any(c in string.ascii_letters for c in val):
            ascii = True
        return ascii

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        if len(password1) < self.PASS_MIN_LENGTH:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.def_error_messages['password_tooshort'],
                code='password_tooshort',
            )

        # check if it contains numbers
        digits = self.has_digits(password1)
        # check for normal char
        ascii = self.has_alpha(password1)

        if not digits and not ascii:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.def_error_messages['password_tooeasy'],
                code='password_tooeasy',
            )

        return password1

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.def_error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        customer = self.user
        customer.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        customer.passwordreset = False
        customer.resetdatetime = timezone.now()
        customer.resetunifier = ""
        if commit:
            customer.save()
        return customer
```

as you can see I have written the line:

```
logger.debug(self.fields[f].error_messages)
```

Which shows me in my console:

```
[Fri Oct 23 04:08:30.837138 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 49999] [23/Oct/2015 04:08:30] DEBUG [syslog:968] {u'required': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7fd39242bbd0>}
[Fri Oct 23 04:08:30.837351 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 49999] [23/Oct/2015 04:08:30] DEBUG [syslog:968] {u'required': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7fd39242bbd0>}
[Fri Oct 23 04:08:30.837561 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 49999] [23/Oct/2015 04:08:30] DEBUG [syslog:968] {u'required': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7fd39242bbd0>}
```

Which is funny, because I have only request the page but not submitted the form! From where does the required come from? Clearly it is not filled out. Because no error message is shown on my website.

My template looks like this:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label>{{ password_form.current_password.label }}</label>
    {{ password_form.current_password }}
    {% for error in password_form.current_password.errors %}
        <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I think you won't be able to do that by adding that code in the `__init__()` method since no validation takes place during initialization. Instead, I'll try adding the code in the `is_valid()` method.

Comment: @RodXavier if you write that as an answer, I will accept it. That solved the problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the code in the `is_valid()` method instead of the `__init__()` method since no validation takes place during initialization.

```
 class UpdatePasswordForm(forms.Form):
     ...
     def is_valid(self):
         is_valid = super(UpdatePasswordForm, self).is_valid()
         for f in self.fields:
             if self.fields[f].error_messages is not None:
                 logger.debug(self.fields[f].error_messages)
                 self.fields[f].widget.attrs['class'] = 'invalid'
         return is_valid
```